# How to import a submodule relative to the caller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Importing a module can be done in a function, then passed back to the caller, take this simple utility.

```
def import_reload_or_none(name, reload=True):
    try:
        mod = __import__(name)
        if reload:
            import importlib
            mod = importlib.reload(mod)
        return mod
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        return None
```

This works for root-level modules, however I'm not sure how this could be done when the function is in another module or when relative imports are used.

How could this function be made to work to replace for eg:

```
from . import my_package_module
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the path to the module you want to import to your function for example:

```
def import_reload_or_none(name, reload=True, path=None):
    mod = __import__(path + '/' + name) if path is not None else __import__(name)
    if reload:
        import importlib
        mod = importlib.reload(mod)
    return mod
```

Then, if you want to import with a relative path you can use

```
import_reload_or_none(my_package_module, path = '.')
```